# Devise Responding With 422 On Sign Up of User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

Not sure why this is happening..I'm running against route `/users.json` and passing in the body as:

`{
"email": "register@register.com",
"password": "ssssssssss"
}`

I'm getting back: `{"errors":{"email":["can't be blank"],"password":["can't be blank"]}}`

uhmmm...what?

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't change your controllers from the default scaffolds, the body should have "user" as the root key:

```
{
   "user": {
     "email": "register@register.com",
     "password": "ssssssssss"
   }
}
```

Also check your server logs that the parameters are actually accepted and parsed correctly.

Comment: hmmm now im getting a 400...I have a proxy running that shows the request correctly...good thought though

Comment: Did you add the outer `{ }` brackets? I left that out in my answer and have edited it in.

Comment: again awesome suggestion but no dice

Comment: maybe something in my schema?

Comment: Hmm, the default devise sign up route is `/users/sign_up.json`, not `/users.json`. If you didn't change it you should try that instead.

Comment: maybe issue with my version of devise

Comment: I edited the answer to use "user" instead of "users". It could also be that devise isn't set up properly at all? Make sure you've added `devise_for :users` to `routes.rb`, restarted your server and are able to access the non-json sign up pages.

Answer (score 1):

Rolling back to version 3.3.2 of Devise fixed...and using @Ivan's req body of:

`{
   "user": {
     "email": "register@register.com",
     "password": "ssssssssss"
   }
}`